# Infer a data property using a object property

Tags: owl, protege

I have an ontology with the Object Property "married with" and a data property "has num child".
Does exists a way (in protege) to infer how many child has Bob given the assertion that Bob is married with Mary and Mary has 1 child?
Or i have to insert manually the data property has num child to Bob?

Comment: SWRL (more to go).

Comment: @StanislavKralin please explain